# Request failed returned code 400. Truncated server response - Google scripts

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, postman

I am very new to APIs. I have successfully built an API in postman and got the data I wanted. I generated the code sample provided by postman in JavaScript format:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Basic ZGVhbGdwwitpflgnBvcnQ6ZldZUmZvVEU5a2hNaFZtUlBlcU1VZ3J5eFRhWXBwN0U3d1hdllBZw==");

var urlencoded = new URLSearchParams();
urlencoded.append("grant_type", "password");
urlencoded.append("username", "123456789");
urlencoded.append("password", "password123!");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: urlencoded,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://accounts.kernel.com/oidc/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

However, I want to build this API in **google scripts** using the function UrlFetchApp. So far I am doing this:

```
function webRelay(){
  var url = 'https://accounts.autoscout24.com/oidc/token';
  
  var username = "123456789";
  var password = "password123!";

  var headers =
  {
    "Content-Type" :  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ,
    "Authorization" : "Basic ZGVhbGdwwitpflgnBvcnQ6ZldZUmZvVEU5a2hNaFZtUlBlcU1VZ3J5eFRhWXBwN0U3d1hdllBZw=="
  }

  var options =
  { 
    "grant_type" : "password",
    "timeout": 0,
    "method" : "post",
    "headers": headers
  };

  // Getting "bad request" here - check the username & password
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var state=result.getContentText(); 

  
  
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Request failed for https://accounts.kernel.com returned code 400.
> Truncated server response: {"error":"invalid_request"} (use
> muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 22, file
> "api")

Comment: Read the documentation and the examples in the doc. You need to use `payload` (similar to `body` in plain js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You want to convert the Javascript in your question to Google Apps Script.
- You have already confirmed that your Javascript worked.

I could understand like above. For this, how about the following modification?

#### Modification points:

- In `options` of UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options)`, there are no properties of`grant_type`and`timeout`.
- When your Javascript is seen, the data is sent as the form data.
- Default "Content-Type" of UrlFetchApp is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
- In your script, `username` is not used.

When above points are reflected to the script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use the modified script, please set the variables of `username`, `password` and `headers`.

```
function webRelay(){
  var url = 'https://accounts.autoscout24.com/oidc/token';
  var username = "123456789";
  var password = "password123!";
  var payload = {
    "grant_type": "password",
    "password": password, 
    "username": username
  }
  var headers = {"Authorization" : "Basic ###"};
  var options = { 
    "method" : "post",
    "headers": headers,
    "payload": payload,
  };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var state = result.getContentText();
  Logger.log(state)
}
```

- In this modified script, your token was removed using `###`. When you use this, please modify it.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Although I think that the request ob above modified script is the same with your Javascript. But unfortunately, I cannot test above script. I apologize for this. So if this didn't work for your situation, I apologize.